Does WSL support snapshot feature like Oracle VirtualBox?
I want to explore the Linux systems programming course by University of Colorado and for that I need to install Linux as a VirtualBox VM on windows as it has a snapshot feature which lets the user restore the progress in case of a crash. The reason for using WSL instead of VB is to save the space, as I think that WSL would not require 200 GB of space as required for VB.
Also, I want to try out bizarre things which might corrupt the WSL or make the kernel panic but I still want to make sure that this does not damage the windows.






Source: https://github.com/cu-ecen-aeld/aesd-assignments/wiki/Virtualbox-Environment-Setup

As 200 GB is recommended here: https://github.com/cu-ecen-aeld/aesd-assignments/wiki/Virtualbox-Environment-Setup, I quoted that.

Recommending 200 GB is weird. Debian or Ubuntu can be installed on a system with less than 8 GB of storage. You should have no issue if you set it to 16 or 32 GB, unless you'll have to install software that require a lot of space, or huge data. But you would have the same issue with WSL.

WSL isn’t technically a VM, while it uses a hypervisor features, it doesn’t have any of the features that a Hyper-V VM would have. If you need those features, use Hyper-V, there is no storage savings…

@A.L so even with Buildroot, Yocto and any other libraries required for kernel development, the space should not go beyond 32 GB, right?

@lousycoder That should work yes, only if this course doesn't need 100 GB of space but that looks unnecessary.

I would first establish whether WSL is a usable substitute for your project. You will not have a proper desktop environment, which is the reason it has a smaller distributable size.
You can comfortably run most Linux distributions with around 30 or less gigabytes, so it is highly likely that the course is recommending that size for a reason (perhaps there are supplementary components required down the line). As a result, using WSL may save you little space anyways.
Should you wish to continue, WSL supports exporting and importing snapshots of your distribution, using the following commands:
wsl --export <Distribution Name> <FileName>
wsl --import <Distribution Name> <FileName>

See this answer and the Microsoft documentation page.

could you address my concern besides space requirements where I suspect inadvertently ending up panicking kernel or corrupting filesystems in case of WSL?

WSL is intentionally designed to have a high degree of interoperability between the host machine and instance. You may be able to modify this, but you will never have the same degree of containerisation as a properly isolated VM, as in VirtualBox.

you can install a desktop environment inside WSL...

WSL does not support snapshots at this time.  You would need install Hyper-V, VirtualBox, or another hypervisor to do snapshotting and reverting easily.

In case of accidental kernel panick or corrupting the file systems, I hope there would be no damage to Windows when I am using the Virtualbox or hyperV, right?

@lousycoder Its a completely separate environment.

Ok, so I can fearlessly use it.
